# celery read files from different computers

Tags: python, celery

I have a program output files. I use celery to output the files with two parallel computers so the output files will distributed in two computers. How can I write a program read files from these two computers?

Answer (score 1):

*This question lacks details.*

I guess you need distributed file system, with which both of your computers can work. There are plenty of solutions: GridFS in MongoDB, HDFS in Hadoop. You can also try more simple solution like SSHFS. In this case, one of your servers will connect to other's server file system. `rsync` can clone remote directory if you are not worried about consistency.